# Can any one tell me what i should write into hibernate.cfg.xml to connect with google cloud sql instance?

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to connect Google Cloud MySQL instance using hibernate.
But I don't know what I need to write into my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

```
<property name="connection.driver.class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://google/DB_Name?cloudSqlInstance=Connestion_Name;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;</property>
<property name="connection.username">User_Name</property>
<property name="connection.password">Password</property>
```

I am writing this but I am getting error

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Google

I had added all IPs into Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Never used google cloud but you should have a public url for your db instance(i think it could be something like www.google.com/xxx/ or similar) and you should replace **//google/DB_Name** with that one

Comment: They give ip address.

Should i try with that ?

Comment: yes, it should be nice if it's a public ip address and not a private one